# Converting the time to MST/PST in in node.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Given a time, I want to convert it to MST/PST timezone in node.js. I am trying the moment module. Is this the right way to do that:

```
var now = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00');
```